# Mapping pages with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a php page and i'm trying to map it with htaccess. The idea is to map the page and if there are no parameters, the page is 1. this is for pagination.

My php page:

```
<?php echo $page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 1; ?>
```

In my htaccess file i have this:

```
RewriteRule     ^noticias/                 noticias.php            [L]
RewriteRule     ^noticias/([0-9]+)/?$      noticias.php?p=$1       [L]
```

If i try to access the page with `localhost/example/noticias.php` and `localhost/example/noticias.php?p=2` everything works.
If i add the first rule, the second rule does not work. And if i remove the first rule, the url wont work.

Tks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^noticias/?$ noticias.php [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^noticias/([1-9]+)/?$ noticias.php?p=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The `RewriteCond` directives would seem to be superfluous and only adding overhead.

Comment: @MrWhite Thank you for the heads up on that one edited

Answer (score 1):

You may use these rules with `MultiViews` turned off:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(noticias)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(noticias)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?p=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```